# Setting Path and Expiration for session cookie in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

Anything I have tried didn't work. Currenly I have following code to change asp.net session cookie expiration date and path, but asp doesn't want to listen to me. I sends same cookie in Set-Cookie header two times sometimes, sometimes it sends it's default cookie ignoring path and expiration date, sometimes it sends everything as expected, and sometimes it doesn't send Set-Cookie at all. What should I do. This drives me nuts :(

My code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /// only apply session cookie persistence to requests requiring session information
  if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
  {
    var sessionState = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState") as SessionStateSection;
    var cookieName = sessionState != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionState.CookieName)
      ? sessionState.CookieName
      : "ASP.NET_SessionId";

    var timeout = sessionState != null
      ? sessionState.Timeout
      : TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

    /// Ensure ASP.NET Session Cookies are accessible throughout the subdomains.
    if (Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null && Session != null && Session.SessionID != null)
    {
      Response.Cookies[cookieName].Value = Session.SessionID;
      Response.Cookies[cookieName].Path = Request.ApplicationPath;
      Response.Cookies[cookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you try using the system call, and not direct change the cookies..

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 20;
```

### update

After your comments, and from what you say to me, is that you try to use the same cookie, for 2 different applications, and set different time outs. But asp.net can keep only one session for every cookie. To solve that you must use 2 different named cookies, and not different cookie path.

On each application directory, on web.config, change the

```
<sessionState cookieName="AppSessionCookieName" ..>
```

Reference for more infos
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100)

Hope this solve the problem.

Comment: The path is OK. I have different instance of same application on same domain. I wan't to set path to allow them to work side by side without changing each other session. Request.ApplicationPath looks good to me too. It's not physical path as I can see so far. It returns something like "/MyApplication" or "/" depending on how it's configured in IIS, but I could as well store this value in Web.Config if I suspect Request.ApplicationPath don't provide what I expect. For now it's not a problem where to get this path but how to pass it to browser.

Comment: Also I found what was an error. On ITest server I had <sessionState timeout="1" /> and it expired too quickly. I couldn't see that on my dev machine because I had different web.config here. But the question about Path is still valid.

Comment: I guess I found answer to Path question myself.

private static HttpCookie CreateSessionCookie(string id)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(Config.CookieName, id);
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    return cookie;
}