# Session values getting lost when cookie path is provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies

We have created a ASP.net project. Client raised few security concerns and one of them was providing domain and path for session cookie. So we provided the path and domain to the cookie, but after that we are not able to retrieve the session values.

I also tried to deploy the website on IIS and maintain the folder hierarchy, still of no use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Session state in asp.net set's it's own cookie also, so you may need to set the path on the Session States auto-generated cookie also...

This question and answer describes how to do that:  [Setting Path and Expiration for session cookie in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513742/setting-path-and-expiration-for-session-cookie-in-asp-net)

Here's a link to different configurations for session handling in asp.net:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am talking about session cookie only. I have already set the path of cookie in response. And that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: hmmm...  Maybe just set the session state to be cookieless which will just pass the session id around in the query string...